# solve for three unknowns with two equations

Tags: diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

Apple cost 97 dollars. Orange cost 56 and lemon cost 3. The total amount spent is 16047 dollars and total fruits bought is 240 and each one is bought atleast one. Calculate how many of each have been bought?

I tried to make these equations: x+ y+ z=240 , 97x+56y+ 3z=16047 but I can't proceed further.

Comment: one needs at least three independent equations to solve it. How is this possible to solve?

Comment: I know. That's why I am confused. Any way to solve it?

Comment: @Susobhan, the OP is presumably looking for positive *integer* solutions.  It's possible there's more than one, but clearly at most finitely many.

Comment: So actually he is trying to find an inequality an upper bound for x,y,z

Comment: @Susobhan, no, this is not the case. Read Barry's comment above.

Comment: Also, sort of off-topic, but those are some _very_ expensive fruits.

Comment: Yeah, I undersatnd now. From $94x+ 53y=15327$ we can substitute x=1,2,3... and y=1,2,3... and see, what are the values of x,y,z

Comment: @Susobhan, the exhaustive approach is one way to go about solving, but Dave is presumably looking for something more elegant. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about solving Diophantine equations to be of much more help here. :/

Comment: This (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations) seems to be directly relevant to the equation in terms of $x$ and $y$, though.

Comment: @DivergentQueries- Yes, i understand

Comment: Even I am confused because there is a need for 3 independent equations. Anyhow , even if someone could tell me the answer. I'll be happy and satisfied. :)

Comment: @Dave, it would help to know something about the context in which you encountered this problem.  In particular, are you expected to be familiar with the Euclidean Algorithm?

Comment: No , I am not. Well,  I am a 12 grade student. I was given this by a friend of mine.

Comment: @BarryCipra, is there a way to solve this problem which is more elementary than the one involving the Euclidean Algorithm?

Comment: @Dave, I expect your best bet is to familiarize yourself with the Euclidean algorithm to solve the problem (see my answer for how you can use it to solve the equation).

Comment: @DivergentQueries, well the exhaustive-search approach mentioned by Susobhan is arguably more elementary, in that it's clear how and why it works.  (If I were going to write a quick and dirty computer program to solve just this one problem and no other, I would loop through the values of $15327-94x$, looking for ones divisible by $53$ rather than trying to implement the Euclidean Algorithm.)  What I was really asking is how much explanation the OP wants or needs.

Comment: @BarryCipra, I understand. Thanks!

Comment: @Dave, thanks for your clarification, and welcome to math.stackexchange!  I hope you can see from the comments and answer that your question is a nice one with some rich mathematics underlying it.  At some point the solution boils down to doing a bunch of arithmetic; what's interesting is to organize and streamline the arithmetic so that you're not just blindly trying one number after another.  That's where the Euclidean Algorithm and the theory of linear diophantine equations come in.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071016041504AAcUcwW) answer to a similar problem to solve your problem in a methodical non-trial-and-error way.

$$\begin{align}
  x +   y +  z &=   240 \\
97x + 56y + 3z &= 16047
\end{align}$$

Combine these two equations to eliminate $x$. Rewrite as a congruence. Subtract the largest multiple of the modulus to simplify the congruence. Rearrange the congruence.

$$\begin{align}
41y + 94z & = 7233 \\
7233 - 94z & \cong 0 mod 41 \\
17 - 94z & \cong 0 mod 41 \\
94z & \cong 17 mod 41
\end{align}$$

Now we start using the repetitive technique in the linked answer.

Rewrite the congruence as an equation with an integer solution. Introduce variables as needed; these are denoted by capital letters. Keep simplifying and rewriting until the fractions are gone.

$$\begin{align}
94z & = 41J + 17 \\
J & = \frac{94z - 17}{41} = 2z + \frac{12z - 17}{41} \\
\text{Let } K & = \frac{12z - 17}{41} \\
\text{Then } z & = \frac{41K + 17}{12} = 3K + \frac{5K + 17}{12} \\
\text{Let } L & = \frac{5K + 17}{12} \\
\text{Then } K & = \frac{12L - 17}{5} = 2L + \frac{2L - 17}{5} \\
\text{Let } M & = \frac{2L - 17}{5} \\
\text{Then } L & = \frac{5M + 17}{2} = 2M + \frac{M + 17}{2} \\
\text{Let } N & = \frac{M + 17}{2} \\
\text{Then } M & = 2N - 17
\end{align}$$

$J$, $K$, $L$, $M$, $N$ all $\in \mathbb N$

Now start plugging back in from bottom up:

$$\begin{align}
L & = 2M + \frac{M + 17}{2} \\
& = 2(2N - 17) + \frac{2N - 17 + 17}{2} \\
& = 5N - 34 \\
\\
K & = 2L + \frac{2L - 17}{5} \\
& = 2(5N - 34) + \frac{2(5N - 34) - 17}{5} \\
& = 12N - 85 \\
\\
z & = 3K + \frac{5K + 17}{12} \\
& = 3(12N - 85) + \frac{5(12N - 85) + 17}{12} \\
& = 41N - 289
\end{align}$$

We are given that $x$, $y$, $z$ all $\gt 0$, so $41N \gt 289$, so $N \ge 8$. Pick $N = 8$ because it's the smallest. Then:

$$\begin{align}
N & = 8 \\
\\
z & = 41N - 289 \\
& = 39 \\
\\
y & = \frac{7233 - 94z}{41} \\
& = \frac{7233 - 94(39)}{41} \\
& = 87 \\
\\
x & = 240 - y - z \\
& = 240 - 87 - 39 \\
& = 114
\end{align}$$

Final solution:$$\require\enclose
\enclose{box}{
\begin{align}
x & = 114 \\
y & = 87 \\
z & = 39
\end{align}}$$

Checking:$$\begin{align}
97x + 56y + 3z & = 97(114) + 56(87) + 3(39) \\
& = 16047
\end{align}$$

If we try $N \ge 9$, we have: $$\begin{align}
N & \ge 9 \\
z & = 41N - 289 \\
& \ge 41(9) - 289 \\
& \ge 80 \\
y & = \frac{7233 - 94z}{41} \\
& \le \frac{7233 - 94(80)}{41} \\
& \le -7
\end{align}$$

So the solution above is the only one.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in the comments that you derived a third equation from the first two, $94x+53y= 15327$, and you are looking for solutions where $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$. This is known as a **linear Diophantine equation in two variables** (with the additional constraint that $x$ and $y$ must be positive). You can find a complete procedure for solving such equations [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html). If you are curious about why this procedure works or if you find yourself confused by the Wolfram page, a more complete explanation is found in [this lecture](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/21-127/lectures/divisibility_5_print.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

From a purely algebraic point of view (forgive me but this is the only way I can think in mathematics), using the two equations you wrote, you could eliminate $x$ and $y$ as a function of $z$. This leads to $$x=\frac{2607+53 z}{41} $$ $$y=\frac{7233-94 z}{41} $$ and you need to find the integer values of $z$ which make $x$ and $y$ integers, greater or equal to $1$. The equation giving $y$ restricts the domain to $1 \le z \le 76$.

One thing you can do, even if not elegant, is to minimize $$\Phi(z)=(x-\lfloor x\rfloor )^2+(y-\lfloor y\rfloor )^2$$ or to solve $$\Psi(z)=(x-\lfloor x\rfloor )+(y-\lfloor y\rfloor )$$ which have a single solution corresponding to $z=39$ and $\Phi(39)=\Psi(39)=0$